# How is NOT(IS NULL) different from IS NOT NULL in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean, boolean-expression

What's wrong with this SQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename  
WHERE columnname NOT (IS NULL)
```

since `IS NULL` is a Boolean value, why doesn't `NOT` negate it?
rather it returns this
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(IS NULL)' at line 2`

Comment: It does.  The negation is `IS NOT NULL`.  You can't put operators in parentheses, so `x (=) 3` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's purely syntax error.

There is no syntax like below

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename  
WHERE columnname (IS NULL)
```

columnname became function in above example. Right example will be

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename  
WHERE columnname IS NULL
```

So if you want to use Not before IS Null you need use it like below:

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename  
WHERE Not (columnname IS NULL)
```

Since (columnname IS NULL)  is the express not (IS NULL)

But the conventional way is to use like below:

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename  
WHERE columnname IS NOT NULL
```

(Above two statements will return the same result.)